# Text field in matrix layout

Tags: sapui5

I want to place a text field in a matrix layout. Please check below code and please suggest how to check XML code errors? Every time I stuck in designing the XML code. Please suggest me how to overcome that.

```
 <core:View 
     xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
     xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
     xmlns="sap.m" 
     xmlns:l="sap.ui.commons.layout"
     controllerName="matrix.matrix" 
     xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <Page title="ytftfhgff">
            <content>
                <l:MatrixLayout layoutFixed="true" columns="4" width="600px" widths="150px,150px,150px,150px">
                    <l:MatrixLayoutRow>
                        <l:MatrixLayoutCell colSpan="4">
                            <Text text="Its a heading" />
                        </l:MatrixLayoutCell>
                    </l:MatrixLayoutRow>
                    <l:MatrixLayoutRow>
                        <l:MatrixLayoutCell>
                            <Label text="First Name"/>
                        </l:MatrixLayoutCell>
                        <l:MatrixLayoutCell>
                            <TextField id="axscx" width="20em"></TextField>
                        </l:MatrixLayoutCell>
                    </l:MatrixLayoutRow>
                </l:MatrixLayout>
            </content>
        </Page>
    </core:View>
```

Thanks in advance,
sriman.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The values of your xmlns attributes look suspicious.  Double-check those.

Answer (score 2):

In general the errors logged by the XMLTemplateParser to the console should be understandable enough to get a basic idea of what's going wrong. In your case it is quite simple. The default namespace is set to "sap.m", i.e. the runtime tries to load the TextField control from that library. This cannot work as sap.m does not have a TextField control.

You can either use the Input control, i.e. replace TextField with Input. Or introduce an additional namespace:

```
xmlns:commons="sap.ui.commons"
```

and define the TextField in the following way:

```
<commons:TextField id="axscx" width="20em"/>
```

I would prefer using the Input field.